# What was at the beginning of Time?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-universe, justice-league, justice-league-unlimited

In the end of *Justice League Unlimited* season 1 (Season 3 of *Justice League*), a crazy nerd from the future (who invented some kind of Time Machine) tried to steal Batman's belt from Watch Tower. Batman, Green Lantern & Wonder Woman followed him to the past and then again to the future in later episode.

In the end of this story, the nerd started to travel to the beginning of Time to reset everything & declare himself god. Before Green Lantern intercepted him in time tunnel & Batman changed programming of his time machine, *a big hand with swirl of stars* was shown at the beginning of Time.

[image: The hand at beginning of time 1]

[image: The hand at beginning of time 2]

[image: Green Lantern and Batman before The hand at beginning of time 1]

[image: Green Lantern and Batman before The hand at beginning of time 2]

What is this? Is it from some kind of mythology? Out of universe answers are allowed..

Comment: It has been reffered to in comics as the "Hand of Creation" but I can't find the source for this.

Comment: I always wonder about it, +1 for asking it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### In Universe

It is supposedly the Hand of Creation (no references), but I suspect it is the hand of [**Krona**](http://greenlantern.wikia.com/wiki/Krona), having gone  back in time to witness the Big Bang, in some perverse way actually causes or assists the event by observing it. In any event, his witnessing the birth of the universe (there was technology involved) caused the creation of the Anti-Matter universe and the multiverse as well.

Krona was an arrogant scientist of Malthus (the species to later be known as the Oans) who desired all the secrets of the Universe including its origins. In his arrogance, he alters the nature of the universe and creates instead a Multiverse.

Krona has the most complicated origin story ever especially since it has been used to explain the creation of:

- the [**Anti-Matter universe**](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Antimatter_Universe),
- the [**Anti-monitor**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Monitor),
- the existence of the [**Multiverse**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse_%28DC_Comics%29),
- the [**creation, maintenance or control of the color-entities**](http://greenlantern.wikia.com/wiki/Krona#The_Brightest_Day)
- the alien entity **[Entropy](http://greenlantern.wikia.com/wiki/Krona#Entropy)** and the cosmically enhanced version of Krona.
- He is also indirectly responsible for the creation of Superboy Prime and the Legion of Superheroes through the involvement of the [**Time Trapper**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Trapper).
- He even schools the [**Grandmaster and Galactus**](http://media.animevice.com/uploads/0/3388/131535-aj_02_45_super.jpg)

#### Out of Universe

The Big Bang in the DC Universe has been the source of contention, a multiversal dumping ground where villains too big to deal with are often sent, or strange storylines are created (See: Time Trapper).

The Multiverse was a construct of the previous Pre-Crisis universe where multiple active timelines interacted. This was a construct of the DC Universe having several companies which formed from the purchase of different comic companies over the years. Golden Age Superheroes were relegated to Earth 2, while more modern versions or Silver Age heroes became the heroes of Earth 1. This feature of the DC Universe became popularized in the famous tale, The Flash of Two Earths.

The Multiverse was temporarily made into a single construct during the Post-Crisis stories, while DC tried to meld all of its previous properties into one cohesive universe with a single timeline. Heroes were eliminated and different versions of characters were either worked into history or eliminated. This fix was later repealed with the Zero Hour crisis and has now been replaced into the New 52 universe where 52 distinct timelines have become the new multiverse. DC will, once again, separate its divergent worlds and use them for alternative storylines. (See: new Justice Society of America)

[image: Krona]

*Krona: Crazed Malthusian with a lust for knowledge so great he fractured the space-time continuum.*

Answer (score 8):

It's part of the DC Universe's history.  Any attempt to view or travel back in time to the start of the universe results in running into that mysterious hand.  In the hand is a swirl of stars, the creation of the cosmos.

[In the comics](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Big_Bang), this was integrated with the origin of the Green Lantern corps, as Krona's (a member of the race who would later take the name Guardians of the Universe) attempt to view the creation of the universe [created evil](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Green_Lantern_Vol_2_40) in the universe (this was later retconned into being the origin of the multiverse that *Crisis on Infinite Earths* destroyed).  In turn, the Guardians of the Universe created the Manhunters, and later the Green Lantern Corps as a sort of penance.

---

It's worth noting that the final episode of *Green Lantern: The Animated Series* similarly features a sequence involving time travel to the dawn of time.  We see the same hand with cosmic swirl.  Eventually the hand closes on the swirl, and the big bang happens.

Comment: The hand is also present here on the second image: http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Big_Bang

Comment: Wonder if this is the same as Master Hand from Super Smash Bros. Melee...